# Change and group rows IDs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with these columns

```
ID     X    Y  
x1.1  0.1  0.2  
x1.2  0.1  0.2  
x1.3  0.1  0.2  
x2.1  0.3  0.4  
x2.2  0.3  0.4  
x3.1  0.5  0.6  
x3.2  0.5  0.6  
...   0.1  0.2
```

And I would like to change all the IDs for the x1.i for x1, x2.i for x2, and so on. So my data frame would look like this:

```
ID     X    Y   
x1    0.1  0.2  
x1    0.1  0.2  
x1    0.1  0.2  
x2    0.3  0.4  
x2    0.3  0.4  
x3    0.5  0.6  
x3    0.5  0.6  
...   ...  ...
```

How could I do it without using a loop?

Regards and thanks for the response in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to match the `.` followed by other characters (`.*`) to end of the string and replace it with `""`

```
df1$ID <- sub("\\..*", "", df1$ID)
df1
#  ID   X   Y
#1 x1 0.1 0.2
#2 x1 0.1 0.2
#3 x1 0.1 0.2
#4 x2 0.3 0.4
#5 x2 0.3 0.4
#6 x3 0.5 0.6
#7 x3 0.5 0.6
```